# Add new column with specific increasing of a quarter using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, that has a quarters column where I would like to add an additional increased quarters column adjacent to it (increased by 2)

Data

```
id  date    
a   Q1 2022 
a   Q1 2022 
a   Q1 2022 
a   Q1 2022 
b   Q1 2022 
b   Q1 2022
```

Desired

```
id  date      new 
a   Q1 2022   Q3 2022
a   Q1 2022   Q3 2022
a   Q1 2022   Q3 2022
a   Q1 2022   Q3 2022
b   Q1 2022   Q3 2022
b   Q1 2022   Q3 2022
```

Doing

```
df['new'] = df.index + 2
```

However this is not adding 2 consistently to the entire column
I am still troubleshooting, any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Consider if date column contains `Q4 2022`, what will the output in that case?

Comment: it is always 2 quarters in the future- it will be Q1 2023

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reformat the strings in `date` in such a way that the resulting date format is `YearQuarter` so that it can be parsed into `PeriodIndex`, now add `2` to this index and `strftime` to convert back to orignal format

```
s = df['date'].str.replace(r'(\S+) (\S+)', r'\2\1')
df['new'] = (pd.PeriodIndex(s, freq='Q') + 2).strftime('Q%q %Y')
```

---

```
  id     date      new
0  a  Q1 2022  Q3 2022
1  a  Q1 2022  Q3 2022
2  a  Q1 2022  Q3 2022
3  a  Q1 2022  Q3 2022
4  b  Q1 2022  Q3 2022
5  b  Q1 2022  Q3 2022
```